# Chrome is displaying things differently than Chrome on another computer

Tags: google-chrome, font-size

I'm having basic margin/padding and font size display issues with Google Chrome.
I have my screen zoom set to 100% and my font size set to medium. I've gone into 'customized fonts' and made sure my settings are the same as my co workers. I've uninstalled and reinstalled and checked over all these display settings again, and still my padding/margins and font sizes are not displaying the same as it is on their machines in the same browser Chrome.

This is not a CSS issue, it is specific to my machine and my install of Google Chrome. I have a reset class applied to the site and in all other browsers things are displaying as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you perhaps using bootstrap? This reminds me of a similar issue i've had in the past

Comment: maybe its just the screen resolution? (or screen size :-)

Comment: Hiroto: No, I'm not! Good suggestion though!
Seismoid: I am comparing my machine to three other machines: Another iMac (same model & OS version as mine), a Macbook and another iMac with a slightly larger screen. Mine is the only one that was displaying differently